# Database schema issue with custom module and l10n

Tags: database, drupal, localization, conflict

I've created .install file for my own module for Drupal 7 with following schema:

```
$schema['press_release_email'] = array(
'fields' => array(
  'id'   => array(
    'type' => 'serial',
    'not null' => TRUE
  ),    
  'email_name' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 255,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => '',
  ),
  'email_address' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 255,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => '',
  ),
),
'primary key' => array('id'),
);
```

When I install it via Drush, I receive error message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 column name is not >unique: INSERT INTO {l10n_update_project} (name, project_type, core, version, >l10n_server, l10n_path, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); Array
>   (
>      [0] => drupal
>      [1] => core
>      [2] => 7.x
>      [3] => 7.22
>      [4] =>
>      [5] => http://ftp.drupal.org/files/translations/7.x/drupal/drupal-7.22.%language.po
>      [6] => 1
>   )

At first my first schema field had a name 'name', then I renamed it, but that didn't help. I cleared cash too.

I hope someone can direct me.

Thank you for attention.

**EDIT**

```
<?php
function press_release_schema() {
$schema = array();

$schema['press_release_email'] = array(
  'fields' => array(
  'id'   => array(
    'type' => 'serial',
    'not null' => TRUE
  ),    
  'email_name' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 255,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => '',
  ),
  'email_address' => array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 255,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => '',
  ),
),
'primary key' => array('id'),
);

 return $schema;
}

function press_release_install() {
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you post your entire .install?

Comment: @ErikAhlswede I've added .install file content